# Fade in Animation for App Start Repeating at Unwanted Times

Tags: java, android, animation

So I decided to have my app start with a fade in animation to just make it have a nice and smooth start. Later on I add a slide in animation when the next activity starts and a slide out animation when I return to it. However when the app crashes or the device drops the app from memory but keeps the most recent activity in multitasking, when I go back to the main page it fades in once more.

Fade in at start:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, 0);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);                   
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Slide out for next activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Next.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
```

Slide in to resume:

```
this.finish();
overridePendingTransition  (R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: What error is thrown on crash?

Comment: Just any crash, my app has no errors now so as far as I know that doesn't happen anymore, I'm thinking it's just whenever onCreate() is called again.

Answer (score 0):

Try only running your animation on activity creation when no savedInstanceState bundle exists (the first time you start this activity)

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, 0);    
}
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);                   
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```